# Can a burnt plug cause issues?

Tags: electrical, socket, cord-and-plug

I had 2 electronics plugged into a double type C plug.

One of them burnt to the point the cable fell off and the other got soldered and I cut off the cable.

I will get it all fixed, but my question is: **Is it safe for the 2 cable-less plugs to stay in the socket until it's fixed or should I shut off electricity to that side of the house as a precaution until then?**

Thank you!

Comment: Till the reason is found to why they burnt, I would turn off the power and at least remove the plugs and replace the outlet.  They are protections to prevent power to burn stuff up, so unless you had a campfire under the outlet, you have a problem, that should not have happen.  Find it, fix it.  Is this a USB type C in a wall/house outlet?

Comment: @crip659 I will fix it, but currently both plugs are stuck in the so until someone can come over to deal with it, could they cause any trouble given theyre not connected to any wire?

Comment: I am thinking this is USB type power on a house wall outlet.  If the wires are burnt enough and connected making a complete circuit, it will use power and produce heat, maybe, maybe not enough.  Replacement of the wall outlet is usually easy, turn off power, check power is off, and take pictures before removing any wire.  Take old one out, put new outlet in.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

By "Type C" you mean a Schuko socket (aka CEE 7/3).

Absolutely none of that is safe.  Not a bit.

Immediately find the circuit breakers or disconnect for the house, shut them all off, test the plug area for voltage if able, and use an insulated tool to pull out those wrecked plugs.

They should be gotten rid of because the failure you describe is unheard-of with safety-certified equipment of the type authorized to be sold in Schuko-type countries.  Proper power cords don't burn up by themselves, and they don't burn up from an excessive load from the appliance. (they're large enough to survive until the supply circuit breaker trips in inverse-time mode, or in the case of UK plugs, they have fuses). However we see a lot of, shall we say "cheap Cheese junk" which uses intentionally too-small conductors, which can and do burn up under load. This stuff is generally sold mail-order from overseas (or Amazon) as the authorities will punish any retailer caught selling it.  Amazon plays under special rules where they are not responsible for the quality of 3rd party seller items shipped through their warehouse.

So it is time to stop using vendors like that and stick to quality items from responsible local sellers.